# PySpark 2.1: Importing module with UDF's breaks Hive connectivity

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm currently working with Spark 2.1 and have a main script that calls a helper module that contains all my transformation methods. In other words:

```
main.py
helper.py
```

At the top of my `helper.py` file I have several custom UDFs that I have defined in the following manner:

```
def reformat(s):
  return reformat_logic(s)
reformat_udf = udf(reformat, StringType())
```

Before I broke off all the UDFs into the helper file, I was able to connect to my Hive metastore through my SparkSession object using `spark.sql('sql statement')`. However, after I moved the UDFs to the helper file and imported that file at the top of my main script, the SparkSession object could no longer connect to Hive and went back to the default Derby database. I also get errors when trying to query my Hive tables such as `Hive support is required to insert into the following tables...`

I've been able to solve my issue by moving my UDFs into a completely separate file and only running the import statements for that module inside the functions that need them (not sure if this is good practice, but it works). Anyway, does anyone understand why I'm seeing such peculiar behavior when it comes to Spark and UDFs? And does anyone know a good way to share UDFs across applications?

Comment: Take a look at [SPARK-19163](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19163). `udf` requires an active session to work, so it will initialize one if one doesn't exist. If you create `UserDefinedFunction` objects in a separate module it has to be imported after you initialize session.

Comment: Thanks @zero323! That's exactly the issue I was having. Glad to see it'll be fixed in 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to Spark 2.2.0 `UserDefinedFunction` eagerly creates `UserDefinedPythonFunction` object, which represents Python UDF on JVM. This process requires access to `SparkContext` and `SparkSession`. If there are no active instances when `UserDefinedFunction.__init__` is called, Spark will automatically initialize the contexts for you.

When you call `SparkSession.Builder.getOrCreate` after importing `UserDefinedFunction` object it returns existing `SparkSession` instance and only some configuration changes can be applied (`enableHiveSupport` is not among these).

To address this problem you should initialize `SparkSession` before you import UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

from helper import reformat_udf
```

This behavior is described in [SPARK-19163](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19163) and fixed in Spark 2.2.0. Other API improvements include decorator syntax ([SPARK-19160](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19160)) and improved docstrings handling ([SPARK-19161](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19161)).